# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, type-conversion, spring-batch

I've written a spring batch job that reads a CSV and writes into SQL server db. The CSV file has some fields of type `Date` and `TimeStamp`. I'm using FlatFileItemReader and JdbcBatchItemWriter.

The Date format in my CSV is **yyyy-MM-dd**
and the TimeStamp format is **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS**

**NOTE: I'm using java.sql.Date and TimeStamp, NOT java.util.Date and TimeStamp**

User class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private Date dateOfJoining;
    private TimeStamp timeStampReg;
...
```

I use the same model class `User` to read from the DB in a different step.

The Reader in Configuration Class looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfigClass{

    
    //Step 1
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> itemReader() {

        FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        flatFileItemReader.setResource(inputResource);
        flatFileItemReader.setName("CSV-Reader");
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<User> lineMapper() {

        DefaultLineMapper<User> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName", "dateOfBirth", "dateOfJoining","timeStampReg"});

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);           

        defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return defaultLineMapper;
    }
...
```

On running the job, I get the errors:

`Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=Path to the CSV file`

`Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date' for property 'dateOfBirth';`

```
Field error in object 'target' on field 'dateOfBirth': rejected value [1998-12-31]; codes [typeMismatch.target.dateOfBirth,typeMismatch.dateOfBirth,typeMismatch.java.sql.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.dateOfBirth,dateOfBirth]; arguments []; default message [dateOfBirth]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date' for property 'dateOfBirth'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date' for property 'dateOfBirth': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

**It gives the same error for other date and timestamp fields(`dateOfJoining` and `timeStampReg`)**

**EDIT:**

I resolved the error for the `Date` type fields by the following solution, But I'm still getting the same error for `TimeStamp` type field.

I created a `custom BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` and override its `initBinder` to add a `CustomDateEditor`.

```
public class MyCustomBeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> extends BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<FSMChequePayment> {

    @Override
    protected void initBinder(DataBinder binder) {
        CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);

        CustomDateEditor editorTimeStamp = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"), true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(TimeStamp.class,editorTimeStamp);
        
    }
}
```

and use its object instead of the actual `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`in the `flatFileItemReader` bean by replacing it with:

`MyCustomBeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new MyCustomBeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();`

PS: The Custom Editor didn't work for `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.TimeStamp`. So I had to Switch to `java.util.Date`. That resolved it for `Date` type but the error still persists for `TimeStamp` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though your batch is only able to split your lines into `String` values, but fails to convert the more exotic types. The [JavaDoc for `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.html) says:

> To customize the way that FieldSet values are converted to the desired type for injecting into the prototype there are several choices. You can inject PropertyEditor instances directly through the customEditors property, or you can override the createBinder(Object) and initBinder(DataBinder) methods, or you can provide a custom FieldSet implementation. You can also use a ConversionService to convert to the desired type through the conversionService property.

I suggest experimenting with some of those alternatives based on which ones fit your need best.

**EDIT:** A possible solution can be to simply use the `ApplicationConversionService` class, which Spring Boot provides out of the box. I set up a [working example on GitHub](https://github.com/ThomasKasene/batch-datetime-mapping) if you want to take a look at my solution and, more importantly, my assumptions about your project. Note that I'm using the `java.sql.*` classes in my example project because the `ApplicationConversionService` works fine with those, seemingly.

```java
@Bean
FieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper() {
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);
    fieldSetMapper.setConversionService(ApplicationConversionService.getSharedInstance());
    return fieldSetMapper;
}
```

Comment: I implemented a Custom ```BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper``` to add a ```CustomDateEditor``` by overiding the ```initBinder```. It resolves it for the type ```Date```, but the problem still persists for type ```TimeStamp```. Though I had to switch from ```java.sql.Date``` to ```java.util.Date```. I've updated the details in my question. You can have a look at the **EDIT** section.

Comment: I amended my answer to provide an actual solution. It seems quite simple to me - see if you like it.