# spring batch : typeMismatch.java.sql.Date,typeMismatch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i'm trying to send this csv file to database with spring batch

users.csv

2021-06-22,test1@gmail.com, testFullname1, testMatricule1, 1234, testUsername1

2021-06-22,test2@gmail.com, testFullname2, testMatricule2, 0000, testUsername2

and i have this error
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date' for property

here's batchConfig

```
package sofrecom.collaborateur.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import sofrecom.collaborateur.model.DAOUser;



@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<DAOUser> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<DAOUser> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<DAOUser>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("users.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<DAOUser>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[] { "dateIntegration","email","fullname","matricule","password","username" });
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<DAOUser>() {{
                setTargetType(DAOUser.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor() {
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<DAOUser> writer() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<DAOUser> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<DAOUser>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<DAOUser>());
        writer.setSql("INSERT INTO user ( date_integration,email,fullname,matricule,password,username) VALUES ( :dateIntegration,:email,:fullname,:matricule,:password,:username)");
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<DAOUser, DAOUser> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }
}
```

and this is user Item proccessor

```
package sofrecom.collaborateur.config;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import sofrecom.collaborateur.model.DAOUser;


public class UserItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<DAOUser, DAOUser> {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserItemProcessor.class);
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Override
    public DAOUser process(final DAOUser person) throws Exception {

        final String password = bcryptEncoder.encode(person.getUsername());
        
        final DAOUser transformedPerson = new DAOUser(person.getDateIntegration(),person.getEmail(),person.getFullname(),person.getMatricule(),password,person.getUsername());

        log.info("Converting (" + person + ") into (" + transformedPerson + ")");

        return transformedPerson;
    }

}
```

any solution please !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64270482/failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-java-lang-string-to-required-type-ja)

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: What did not work? You seem to have a field of type `java.sql.Date` in your domain model class, and this type is not supported by default and requires a custom converter. Please update the question with the changes that you tried and did not work or provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: i didn't find nothing to try , that's what am i asking , i want a solution to try it and if you can help me how to work with custom converter and thanks .

Comment: ok no problem, I will add an answer with an example.

Comment: I added an answer with a complete example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` does not know, by default, how to convert a String like `2021-06-22` to an object of type `java.sql.Date` (which is the field `dateIntegration`) in your domain object `DAOUser`. The way to tell this mapper how to deal with custom conversions is by registering a `ConversionService`. This conversion service should have a converter from `String` to `java.sql.Date` registered in it. Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<DAOUser> reader() {
    DefaultConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
    conversionService.addConverter(new Converter<String, Date>() { // java.sql.Date
        @Override
        public Date convert(String s) {
            return Date.valueOf(s);
        }
    });
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<DAOUser> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setConversionService(conversionService);
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(DAOUser.class);

    FlatFileItemReader<DAOUser> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("users.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<DAOUser>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] { "dateIntegration","email","fullname","matricule","password","username" });
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

You can find a complete example based on what you shared in [this repository](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/main/issues/so68121766).

Comment: yes it's working now thanks a lot , but still need 2 other solutions if you can help me of course, the first one is i want to encode the password from csv to db with PasswordEncoder like " 1234 to '$2a$10$5jGCrJUVoAIkXMRFCFBv.uumpQDPsPzJK756ZHasn16p25j.cutRK' " , second is how to convert and integer id from csv to a specific class like " a user have an id_function 1 (manager) but this id_function type is Function and it's dao class like daouser " , and thank's a lot for your help